# Set the Delegate on SubView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a splitViewController that has a master and detail view controllers. The code below is from the master and it creates the new view in the detail:

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.defaultSettingsMenuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

[self.detailViewController.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

detailViewController is a global instance of DetailViewController. In the detailViewController, I have many textFields and need to utilize the UITExtFieldDelegate. However, I think that the detailViewController isn't self at that point, and that's why I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors on using the TextFieldDelegate methods in detailViewController.

EDIT: I have now found that the subView delegate methods only work for the viewController I setup as the rootViewCOntroller relationship from within Storyboard. Ex. If I have 6 views in the default menu settings above, whichever one I have setup as the first and root view in storyboard will work correctly. Any and all other subviews shown (from making a new selection in the master view) will not work properly. I think this will help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all I needed, the second line:

```
UIViewController *viewController= [self.detailViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.defaultSettingsMenuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

if (self.detailViewController.childViewControllers.count >= 1) {
    NSLog(@"childViewControllers: %@",self.detailViewController.childViewControllers);
    [[self.detailViewController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0] removeFromParentViewController]; 

}

[self.detailViewController addChildViewController:viewController];

[self.detailViewController.view addSubview:viewController.view];
```

EDIT: I've updated my answer with the if look to remove viewControllers from the stack. Slightly hacky, but functional.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with storyboards, but I don't see you setting the `detailViewController`'s delegate anywhere. You probably need to have something like `self.detailViewController.delegate = self;` somewhere before you yield control over to the subview.

Comment: when I NSLog the delegate from the subView I get detailViewController

Comment: Then I don't fully understand what your problem is =\

Comment: Frankly, I don't think I do either. I don't understand why if the delegate is set correctly a subView would crash from a simple UITextField Delegate.

Comment: Identify the line of code that breaks (with breakpoints), and start stepping into it until you find the system function that is returning bad data? It's annoying, but it works. Usually.

Comment: I am out of my scope then. Storyboards are black magic to me. I might be able to come up with something, but not without learning the whole concept - which I don't have the time for. Good luck though.